# To add one array data into another array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array named

```
$scope.workingSchedules=[
                       {
                  workingDay:"MONDAY",
                  workingHours:[{fromTime:'1222',toTime:'1300'}]
                      },
                  workingDay:"MONDAY",
                  workingHours:[{fromTime:'1222',toTime:'1300'}]
                     ];
```

It can store multiple days of week.

I have another array with all days of week written.

```
$scope.workingTime = [ 
        {   workingDay: 'MONDAY',
            workingHours: []
        },
        {   workingDay: 'TUESDAY',
            workingHours: []
        },
        {   workingDay: 'WEDNESDAY',
            workingHours: []
        },
        {   workingDay: 'THURSDAY',
            workingHours: []
        },
        {   workingDay: 'FRIDAY',
            workingHours: []
        },
        {   workingDay: 'SATURDAY',
            workingHours: []
        },
        {   workingDay: 'SUNDAY',
            workingHours: []
        }
     ];
```

What I want is to add 1st array (workingSchedules[]) data into 2nd array(workingTime[])  and also keeping uncommon workingDays as it is in the 2nd array . 1 st array can have multiple days in it .

Here is my code:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.workingTime[i].length;i++)
    {
        for (var j=0;j<$scope.workingSchedules[j].length;j++)
        {
          if($scope.workingTime[i].workingDay==$scope.workingSchedules[j].workingDay)
          {
            $scope.workingTime[i]=$scope.workingSchedules[j];

           }

        }
   }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I don't see anything you need help with... You'll need to explain what the problem is; what your inputs are and what the expected outputs are, any errors in the console, etc.

Comment: So if you have multiple entries for "MONDAY", do you want to have multiple entries?

Comment: problem was with i<$scope.workingTime[i].length , instead of using correctly as i<$scope.workingTime.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems here. Your first array is invalid, as you try to insert key/values to it. Either declare it as an object or put all its items as objects like so:`{workingDay:"MONDAY"},` instead of `workingDay:"MONDAY",`.

Then your loops are weirdly indexed. Try `i<$scope.workingTime.length` instead of `i<$scope.workingTime[i].length`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, problem was with i<$scope.workingTime[i].length

Answer (score 0):

When you do  `$scope.workingTime[i]=$scope.workingSchedules[j];`, you are replacing the value. You should rather use `.concat` to merge values.

#### Solution with duplicate entries

```js
var data=[{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"TUESDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"WEDNESDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"THURSDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"FRIDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"SATURDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"SUNDAY",workingHours:[]}]
var workingSchedules=[{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[{fromTime:"1222",toTime:"1300"}]},{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[{fromTime:"1222",toTime:"1300"}]}];

data.forEach(function(o) {
  var f = workingSchedules.filter(function(item) {
    return item.workingDay === o.workingDay;
  });
  if (f.length)
    o.workingHours = o.workingHours.concat(f.reduce(function(p, c) {
      return p.workingHours.concat(c.workingHours)
    }));
});

console.log(data)
```

#### Solution with unique values

```js
var data=[{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"TUESDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"WEDNESDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"THURSDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"FRIDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"SATURDAY",workingHours:[]},{workingDay:"SUNDAY",workingHours:[]}];
var workingSchedules=[{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[{fromTime:"1222",toTime:"1300"}]},{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[{fromTime:"1222",toTime:"1300"}]},{workingDay:"MONDAY",workingHours:[{fromTime:"1400",toTime:"1700"}]}];

data.forEach(function(o) {
  var f = workingSchedules.filter(function(item) {
    return item.workingDay === o.workingDay;
  });
  if (f.length) {
    o.workingHours = o.workingHours.concat(f.reduce(function(p, c) {
      var exists = p.some(function(item) {
        return item.fromTime === c.workingHours[0].fromTime && item.toTime === c.workingHours[0].toTime;
      });
      return exists ? p : p.concat(c.workingHours);
    }, []));
  }
});

console.log(data)
```